# Solution to weird Windows Phone 7 navigation problem

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a really strange issue relating to how I handle navigation in an application, and that application now being rejected from AppHub (after being successfully approved a number of times on the same code base... grr)

1. currently I am capturing the first navigation of the application and routing it an "add item" page in the App.cs using the example found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)
2. the user then adds an "item"
3. the user is taken to the "main" page again, but stay there are there is now 1 "item" to show in a list
4. the user then can view a "detail" page of this item where they can select to delete the current item. when they do that I redirect them to the "main" page again.
5. this navigation then fires the same thing that happened in step 1
   and they are routed to an "add" page

the problem with the above process, is that if the user hits "back" on the routed page in step 5 they don't go anywhere as they are routed back to the current page (because there are no items on the page previous and this fires the app.cs routing event to take them to the add page). if I *did* allow for them to go back, the actual first page they would be able to go back to is 3 nav steps back, when they first added the item - as they are on the "add item" page already, this would be pointless.

The apphub store testers say that in this instance, the application should close. I really don't know how the f&*k I am meant to make this happen, as there is no "go back until close" action I can call...

thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user decides to "delete" the current item, you shouldn't navigate *forward* to the main page, leaving the deleted item in the navigation stack. You should navigate *back* to the main page. That way the navigation stack will be empty, and if they navigate back again, the app will close.

(The same is true at step 3, of course - when the item is added, navigate *back* to the main page. You don't want the "add" page as part of the navigation stack; that action has been completed.)

Comment: i do navigate "back" but in my "main" page if there is no items, i go back again

Comment: @Doug: I'd expect the main page to show an option for adding an item, if there aren't any. Then the user can choose whether to add one or whether to quit by pressing back.

Answer (score 1):

The single best advice I read on WP7 navigation was "if you don't have to, don't use it." I've almost stopped using it all together and just use "MainPage.xaml" for loading/unloading user controls that do this kind of stuff. I completely control the Back button as needed. It has saved me so much headache. The important thing to realize is that the Navigation pages are really just mimicking a website and it's pages - many apps do not fit that paradigm (as they are apps, not websites). So, if you don't have to use Navigation, don't use it.

So in your case, if you just managed everything on MainPage.xaml, you would use a number of If/Then statements in `OnBackKeyPress` and if one meets your criteria, do an `e.Cancel = true;` and show/load/etc. your thing. If not, let the app navigate out of itself - i.e. exit.

For tombstoning, just let the `OnNavigatedTo` in MainPage.xaml handle loading the right user control received from tombstoned information retrieved from `Application_Activated`.